# How to measure the similarity of an object is to its own cluster or to other clusters

Tags: python, clustering

I have data (5 different vectors of samples A, B, C, D, and E) and I cluster this data into 3 clusters using AgglomerativeClustering with the Wasserstein distance as the metric.

```
data= np.array([
    [5, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 6, 0, 2],
    [7, 2, 0, 0],
    [3, 6, 0, 0],
    [7, 0, 0, 2]])
```

I used the following code to cluster data into three clusters

```
def wasserstein_distance_function(f1, f2):
    min_cost = np.inf
    f1 = f1.reshape((1, 4)) #1 represents one vector [], and 4 represents how many elements in this vector (no. classes)
    f2 = f2.reshape((1, 4))
    for l in np.linspace(0.8, 1.2, 3):
        for k in np.linspace(0.8, 1.2, 3):
            cost = distance.cdist(l * f1, k * f2, 'sqeuclidean')
            row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
            curr_cost = cost[row_ind, col_ind].sum()
            if curr_cost < min_cost:
                min_cost = curr_cost
    return min_cost


def pairwise_wasserstein(points):
    """
    Helper function to perform the pairwise distance function of all points within 'points' parameter
    """
    for first_index in range(0,points.shape[0]):
        for second_index in range(first_index+1,points.shape[0]):
            print("First index: ", first_index, ", Second index: ", second_index,
                  ", Distance: ", wasserstein_distance_function(points[first_index],points[second_index]))


distance_matrix = np.asarray([
    [wasserstein_distance_function(data[first_index], data[second_index]) 
         for first_index in range(len(data))] 
             for second_index in range(len(data))])

distance_matrix
```

The output of this matrix:

```
array([[ 0.  , 35.84, 10.24, 30.72,  4.52],
       [35.84,  0.  , 35.84,  5.12, 46.08],
       [10.24, 35.84,  0.  , 20.48,  5.12],
       [30.72,  5.12, 20.48,  0.  , 35.84],
       [ 4.52, 46.08,  5.12, 35.84,  0.  ]])
```

then I used AgglomerativeClustering to cluster this matrix

```
clusterer = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=3, affinity="precomputed", linkage="average", distance_threshold=None)

clusterer.fit_predict(distance_matrix)
```

**output:** array([1, 0, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

So, the dataframe that contains samples, values (vectors), and cluster

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'samples': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   'values': [[5, 0, 2, 2],[1, 6, 0, 2],[7, 2, 0, 0],[3, 6, 0, 0],[7, 0, 0, 2]],
                  'cluster': [1, 0, 2, 0, 1]})

df
```

output:

```
    samples values  cluster
0   A   [5, 0, 2, 2]    1
1   B   [1, 6, 0, 2]    0
2   C   [7, 2, 0, 0]    2
3   D   [3, 6, 0, 0]    0
4   E   [7, 0, 0, 2]    1
```

Assuming after a round, the value of (B) change from `[1, 6, 0, 2]` to `[7, 1, 0, 2]`

I would like to measure whether sample (B) still belongs to its own cluster (0) or should move to other clusters.

```
 samples values  cluster
0   A   [5, 0, 2, 2]    1
1   B   [7, 1, 0, 2]    ?
2   C   [7, 2, 0, 0]    2
3   D   [3, 6, 0, 0]    0
4   E   [7, 0, 0, 2]    1
```

I am looking for different methods such as math formulas, or other techniques than the silhouette index.

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless many more details come. Object B belonged to cluster "0" on some grounds. What were those grounds? How did the clusters appear (method)? What similarity ruled the process of cluster formation? etc.

Comment: @ttnphns more details have been added.

Comment: There is a general theoretical difficulty worth to keep in mind. You are asking, is an updated point still a good member of the cluster. You can compute the average dist. from the point to the cluster, to other clusters; you then can compare. But that doesn't actually answers the question, because when that point, prior its update, had entered its cluster in the course of the agglomerative clustering, it might have entered on different ground than the individual distance point-cluster. It might, for example, enter because of other points it had associated with earlier on steps (a subcluster).

Comment: In short, a reason why a point may be a good/bad candidate for a cluster "now" (when the clusters are there) is not necessarily that same reason why the point was taken/rejected "then" (when the clustering algo acted).

Comment: @ ttnphns, thank you for your clarification, I understand your point!  I think that computing the average dist is a good solution, do you think there is another solution? since May later also be in a different round, some sample change their vector value, so we should check weather its still belong to the current cluster or change to another.

Comment: Sure, you can compare point-group distances and do it repeatedly, and reassign points based on that. My warning was about that such "now" reasons of (re)assignment don' necessarily coincide with the "then" reasons at cluster (agglomerative) nascent.

Comment: The Silhouette index (why you dismissed it?) is a nice tool  because it shows you how much stronger or weaker is the reason to keep a point in its present cluster rather than in a next closest to it cluster.

Comment: @ttnphns  I already used the Silhouette index, so I looking for other methods.

Comment: @ttnphns could you compute the average dist with example for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @ttnphns could you compute the average distance with example for my code

I'll give the general guide for that.

**Average distance between every point and every group of points**

Let $\bf D$ be the square symmetric matrix `n x n` of distances (dissimilarities) between `n` points, with zero diagonal.

Let $\bf G$ be the `n x k` indicator matrix of group (cluster) membership of the points. With value 1 = belongs to the group, value 0 = doesn't belong to the group. (In general case, a point may belong to one, to more than one group or belong to none; that is, an individual row sum can be any up to `k`, even 0.)

Let $\bf f$ be the row vector of frequencies in the groups, $\text {csum}(\mathbf {G})$, "csum" meaning the column sum. And populate that row into the matrix: $\bf F = [1]f$, where [1] is the column of ones of length `n`.

Then $\bf \frac{DG}{F}$ is the `n points x k groups` matrix of average distances: element ij in it is the average distance between point i and points of group j. If you want the average distances be "leave-one-out", that is, the zero distance of a point to itself not participating in the averaging (when the point i belongs to group j containing >1 points), the $\bf F$ in the formula is first modified as follows: 1) $\bf F'= F-G$; 2) $\mathbf {F= F'}+ \text{not}(\mathbf F')$, where "not" here means this complement recoding operation: `positive element -> 0; nonpositive element -> 1` .